# How to count tag from other unique tag

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I want to count distinct tag from other unique tag.

For example I have 5 row data:

```
tags: account=00001, bucket=A
tags: account=00001, bucket=A
tags: account=00001, bucket=B
tags: account=00005, bucket=A
tags: account=00005, bucket=C
```

I want to count total unique `bucket` in unique `account`

Expected

```
total = 4
```

Because the two first row are duplicated, then total of them are `1`

```
tags: account=00001, bucket=A
tags: account=00001, bucket=A
```

How could I do it? Thanks!